# SignalR as a Service Hubs query

Tags: azure, azure-signalr

Been recently exploring Azure SignalR as a Service. I'm very confused.

I've got the following Hub written in serverless:

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyHub : ServerlessHub
    {
        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public IActionResult Negotiate([HttpTrigger(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] MyModel req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "MyHub")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(connectionInfo.Url + ",," + connectionInfo.AccessToken);
            return new OkObjectResult(Negotiate());
        }
            
        [FunctionName(nameof(OnConnected))]
        public async Task OnConnected([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} has connected");
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(OnDisconnected))]
        public async Task OnDisconnected([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} has disconnected");
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
    <script>
        let messages = $('#messages');

        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://localhost:7111/api")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build()

        connection.on("OrderEvent", (order, msg) => {
            console.log('new message' + order + msg);
        });

        connection
        .start()
        .catch(console.error);
    </script>
```

The client connects but

1. OnConnected doesn't log in my Azure function window
2. OnDisconnected doesn't log in my Azure function window
3. How do I send direct messages to a client?
4. How do I get a subset of clients to send a message to? Eg groups?

At the moment, whoever gets connected to my hub gets all the updates.